# How to select highest quality version of a photo?

Tags: linux, photo

I have many different versions of the same photo in JPEG files. I need a command-line tool or library running on Linux which selects the highest quality version from the available versions. Taking a look (and zooming in) at the files one-by-one is not an option, because I need to repeat this for a few thousand sets of photos. I already know which photos are versions of each other.

The simplest approximate solution to this is selecting the image file with the largest width and height. This doesn't work when there are image A and image B; image B was created by scaling image A down by a factor 2, then scaling the result up by a factor of 3. In this case image A has more information and is of higher quality, but image B has larger dimensions. I need a solution which selects image A in this case and similar cases.

Comment: Tough problem. [This](https://ece.uwaterloo.ca/~z70wang/publications/icip02.pdf) may serve as a starting point.

Comment: Doesn't this reflect on the files' sizes? I would assume, that a scaled up JPEG image would take less space, than an image with the same original size. Maybe you can develop some heuristic based on the file size, the compression ratio, and the width/heigh as features?

Comment: I would probably start from https://www.google.com/search?q=measure+image+entropy

Answer (score 1):

The "quality" of a picture is not an easy thing to measure, and may very well be subjective. That said, there are two approximate solutions that come to mind.

- File size: as @qqilihq suggests, the file size of a jpeg will roughly reflect the quality of a photo. In the example you give, where a file is scaled down and then back to full size, you would expect the original (non-scaled) version to have a larger file size. The details lost in scaling down the jpeg will no longer be taking up space in the file. Seems easy to test, at least.
- You may be able to extract useful information from the jpeg's metadata. This will likely vary greatly by the programs used to edit the jpegs and the specification of the jpegs. Here are two resources: [Exif](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchangeable_image_file_format) and one from [Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/metadata/doc-files/jpeg_metadata.html).

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Yes, I can use the combination of file size, width and height as a signal, but additional research has to be done how to combine these to a reliable score. I forgot to mention that the input files don't have any metadata.